# Tor updated and now won't work on my system(OSX 10.7.5). Is there a way to get rid of that update?

Tags: mac, update

The title pretty much says it all.

I've been using TOR for about two years with no problems after any update…..until now!

I'm on a mac(OSX 10.7.5 Lion) and while it's not the newest(or oldest), i run into very few problems. **This one is major for me though.**

Is there a way, at this point, to delete the update and run the previous version? 
                             Possibly somewhere in the application package contents there is something to look for??

If not, is there a place to download(safely) any version pre-update? I don't see it on the TOR website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanx

BTW, This is my first time using the stack exchange so i apologize if breaking any etiquette rules.

Comment: https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.5.2/ has the old versions (temporarily!) but I'd much prefer you describe the problem that you're having so we can try to resolve that. Also try uninstalling the app and deleting the `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/` folder (this will delete any bookmarks you have, etc) and reinstalling 7.0 (It has many advantages over the 6.5 series).

Comment: The problem they're having is that they are running an OS that is no longer supported by Mozilla's ESR as of ESR52, because the last time OSX 10.7.5 got any security updates was in 2014.

Comment: Same problem here. When I clicked on the link dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.5.2 for the old versions, it opened a 404 NOT FOUND page. So now what? If I were able to revert to the previous version, would it even be safe to use?

Answer (score -1):

For older versions, you can check this url:
https://github.com/TheTorProject/gettorbrowser/releases

Answer (score -1):

All versions are on the official Tor website: https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser

Comment: You should *never* run old versions of Tor Browser and recommending it is reckless and dangerous.